# How to get Joomla Article Category List using API

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I was trying to retrieve list of categories and sub-categories using code.

Expected output -

```
Root Category 
   1st Level Category 1
   1st Level Category 2
      2nd Level Category 1
      2nd Level Category 2
   1st Level Category 3
```

This will be a category navigation. **Logged users will see it depending on View Access Level**.

**Method 1 -**

I took categories like below -

```
    $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);
    $category = $categories->get('root');
```

It gives huge object array (part of it pasted here).

```
object(JCategoryNode)[80]
  public 'id' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'asset_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'lft' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'rgt' => string '13' (length=2)
  public 'level' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'extension' => string 'system' (length=6)
  public 'title' => string 'ROOT' (length=4)
  public 'alias' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'published' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'checked_out' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'checked_out_time' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'access' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'params' => string '{}' (length=2)
  public 'metadesc' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'metakey' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'metadata' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'created_user_id' => string '42' (length=2)
  public 'created_time' => string '2011-01-01 00:00:01' (length=19)
  public 'modified_user_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'modified_time' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'hits' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'language' => string '*' (length=1)
  public 'numitems' => null
  public 'childrennumitems' => null
  public 'slug' => string '1:root' (length=6)
  public 'assets' => null
  protected '_parent' => null
  protected '_children' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(JCategoryNode)[20]
          public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'asset_id' => string '27' (length=2)
          public 'parent_id' => string 'root' (length=4)
          public 'lft' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'rgt' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'level' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'extension' => string 'com_content' (length=11)
          public 'title' => string 'Uncategorised' (length=13)
          public 'alias' => string 'uncategorised' (length=13)
          public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'published' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'checked_out' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'checked_out_time' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'access' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'params' => string '{"target":"","image":""}' (length=24)
          public 'metadesc' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'metakey' => string '' (length=0)
```

How can i get names of parent categories and its child categories as i needed ? Note that i need it to be filtered using view access levels.

**Method 2 -**

Took autherized view levels of logged user

```
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($userid);
```

Loaded it to a array -

```
foreach ($levels as $level){
            $vacl[] = "access = ".$level;
        }
```

Executed a DB query -

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select(array('extension', 'title', 'access','params'));
        $query->from('#__categories');

        $query->where($vacl,'OR')->where('extension ='.$db->quote('com_content'),'AND');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Problem with this is OR and AND did not work as expected. How can i correct it ?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look to the com_content's categories model (components/com_content/models/categories.php). Also to the JTableNested class on the Joomla's wiki.

Categories are modeled using a nested set implementation of a tree. You can learn more about it by searching that concept on google.

Comment: I already looked into that. But cound't make it work. @danielperaza